# Create a completely .exe with opencv in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I was creating a project in Visual Studio with OpenCV and it runs fine. But I cannot just run the compiled .exe file to another computer. Because it does not have opencv or c++. So please help me on how to create an installer program so that the computer does not have to install opencv or c++ and running the project?

Comment: You can use the Setup Wizard template, it is still there in VS 2010.

Comment: You can compile it on Release and copy openCV release dlls to the same folder should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool to find dlls your program depends on. Find the dlls on your system, and copy them to your program distribution (to folder that contains executable file).